# Does there exist a notion of Chern classes in intersection cohomology?

Tags: complex-geometry, line-bundles, chern-classes, intersection-cohomology, complex-analytic-spaces

First of all: I apologize for my mistakes, I'm a freshman in intersection cohomology.

---

Let $X$ be a (compact) complex analytic space, let $L$ be a line bundle over $X$.

Can one define a notion of first Chern class $c_1(L)\in IH^2(X)$ for $L$? Does there exist a such construction? Any reference?

Thanks in advice.